# Monaco Editor, best way to add code when new line added?

Tags: monaco-editor

For a client I need to provide a Web Ide to edit yaml file. So, Monaco Editor seems to be the perfect choice.

One requested feature is:

> add list item ( - ) for a new line if the previous one is a list item

I used `onDidChangeModelContent()` to detect change and 
I figure out how to add this "-" after a new line added but my problem is cursor stay before "-".

I try `setPosition()` or use `executeEdits()` but after `onDidChangeModelContent()` execution, some code override cursor position ...

So, may be, it's not the good way to do it ? any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `editor.onDidType`, which I believe is not in the docs (that means it might be gone by the time v1.0 comes out).

```
editor.onDidType(text => {
  const bulletText = '- ';

  const insertBullet = (pos) => {
    const range = new monaco.Range(pos.lineNumber, pos.column, pos.lineNumber, pos.column);
    editor.executeEdits('new-bullets', [{identifier: 'new-bullet', range, text: bulletText}])
  }

  if (text === '\n') {
    const model = editor.getModel();
    const position = editor.getPosition();
    const prevLine = model.getLineContent(position.lineNumber - 1);
    prevLine.trim().indexOf(bulletText) === 0 && insertBullet(position);
  }
})
```

I haven't actually tested this, but it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it when I get back from vacation and let you know.

Comment: Thanks is working, I just have to add a `setPosition` at then end of `insertBullet` function because added bullet was selected, so was deleted on first key strokes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Benny, it's working now. Just need to add `setPosition` at the end of `insertBullet` function.

```
editor.onDidType(text => {
  const bulletText = "- ";

  const insertBullet = pos => {
    const range = new monaco.Range(
      pos.lineNumber,
      pos.column,
      pos.lineNumber,
      pos.column
    );
    editor.executeEdits("new-bullets", [
      { identifier: "new-bullet", range, text: bulletText }
    ]);

    // Set position after bulletText
    editor.setPosition({
      lineNumber: pos.lineNumber,
      column: pos.column + 2
    });
  };

  if (text === "\n") {
    const model = this.editor.getModel();
    const position = this.editor.getPosition();
    const prevLine = model.getLineContent(position.lineNumber - 1);
    prevLine.trim().indexOf(bulletText) === 0 && insertBullet(position);
  }
});
```